# Javascript Selection and Selection appears in a div

Tags: php, javascript

If anyone could be of assistance with my problem then that would be great! I have my script so far that when you click on one of three anchor links the picture corresponding to that anchor link appears in a DIV, and then on the second selection it appears in the div next to that one, and the same with the third, I am trying to work out how to remove the image from the DIV so I am able to reselect an option and the new selection to be placed in the DIV that is empty....my example only shows 3 selections to choose from but this will be 24 soon.

Also how I can retrieve different information from the database to show in the DIVS and to be to able to submit certain data to the database depending on the selection you choose.

Thanks very much for you time! and any suggestions would be appreciated!.

regards,
alistair

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var pos = 0;
function showPic (whichpic) { 
if (document.getElementById) { 
try {
if ((document.getElementById('placeholder1').src+
document.getElementById('placeholder2').src+
document.getElementById('placeholder3').src).search(whichpic.href) > -1)
throw "blah";
document.getElementById('placeholder'+ ++pos).src = whichpic.href;
//document.getElementById('placeholder2').src = whichpic.href;
//document.getElementById('placeholder3').src = whichpic.href;
if (whichpic.title) { 
document.getElementById('desc').childNodes[0].nodeValue = whichpic.title; 
} else { 
document.getElementById('desc').childNodes[0].nodeValue =           whichpic.childNodes[0].nodeValue; 
}
return false; 
} catch(e) {
alert("u mad?");
return false;
}
} else { 
return true; 
}
}
</script>

<div style="border: 1px solid #999; padding: 1em; margin: 0 0 15px 0;">
<ul>
<li><a onclick="return showPic(this)" href="http://jsfiddle.net/img/ico-add-       resource.png" title="img 1">img 1</a></li>
<li><a onclick="return showPic(this)" href="http://jsfiddle.net/img/info-close.png"      title="img 2">img 2</a></li>
<li><a onclick="return showPic(this)" href="http://jsfiddle.net/img/keys.png"  title="img    3">img 3</a></li>
</ul>

<p id="desc">Choose an image to begin</p>
<img id="placeholder1" src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/shadow.gif" alt="" />
<img id="placeholder2" src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/shadow.gif" alt="" />
<img id="placeholder3" src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/shadow.gif" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: Which server side language do you use? ASP.Net? PHP? Python? Node.js? You cannot use the browser's JavaScript to pull content from the database.

Comment: Hi yes I am using PHP, really all i would need is to somehow have each selection (anchor link) as a value of some kind so I can then have a separete part which sends the value to the databse? I am not so interested in pulling in information but I need to somehow send information to the database, IE if the selections are 1,2,3 to the then send the values 1,2,3 to the database? using php I assume as you cannot in javascript. Thanks!

Comment: if anyone could help it would be great!

Comment: I'm sorry if I couldn't help you because I'm not familiar with PHP. I've tagged it so that others can get it.

Comment: No problem thanks for what you was able to do!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, I see that you declare a variable `pos` and initialize it to 0.  Then, each time the user clicks to display a picture, `pos` is read to see how many pictures are displayed and then find the id of the element where the next picture is displayed.  Finally, you increment `pos`.

If you want to be able to remove pictures so that the user can select new ones, then you'll need to use a more sophisticated sytem.  `pos`, a number, can be used to tell how many pictures that user has displayed, but if the user begins to remove pictures, `pos` cannot tell you *which ones*.

I would suggest that you use an array to tell which elements have pictures displayed in them.

```
var display = [ false, false, false ];
```

When the user displays a picture in `placeholderX`, do

```
display[X] = true.
```

When the user removes the picture from `placeholderX`, do

```
display[X] = false.
```

When the user wants to display a new picture, do something like

```
var i;
for(i=0; i<=3; i++) {
    if (display[i]==false) {
        showPictureAtElement('placeholder' + i.toString());
        display[i]=true;
        break;
    {
}
```

Does that help?

Comment: ah great thanks! that helped!. All I need is for 3 pictures to be shown at one time, basically the user will be selecting drivers from the list and he can only choose 3 different drivers. Then I will have to find a way to submit the selections to php so I can enter them into the database.

Thanks a lot rice flour cookies!

Comment: I would suggest jQuery ajax for submitting the selections to php.  I use ASP.net and jQuery ajax works great for submitting selections.